# функция removeVowels принимает строчку doc и возвращает ее без гласных

Tags: javascript

Напиши функцию removeVowels, которая принимает строчку doc и возвращает строчку, где все гласные из doc удалены. Гласные для этой задачи считаются буквы aeiouy в любом регистре.
(Массив использовать нельзя)

вот мой код:

```
function removeVowels(doc) {
  let x;
  let counter = 0;
  for(const element of doc){
    if(doc[counter] !== 'a' && doc[counter] !== 'e' && 
    doc[counter] !== 'i' && doc[counter] !== 'o' && 
    doc[counter] !== 'u' && doc[counter] !== 'y'){
     x += doc[counter];
    }
    counter++;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Если ввести слово "document" должно вернуть "dcmnt", а я получаю "undefineddcmnt". Почему так?

Comment: Молодец. А вопрос в чём?

Comment: Если ввести слово "document" должно вернуть "dcmnt", а я получаю "undefineddcmnt". Почему так?

Comment: как минимум потому что у тебя написано `let x` без инициализации, а он по умолчанию `undefined`

Comment: Спасибо большое) все получилось

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию значение переменной `undefined`.

Переменная `x` нигде не инициализируется, поэтому ее значение `undefined`.

При первом сложении производится преобразование в строку `"undefined"`, которая и выводится в начале результата.

Для решения достаточно инициализировать переменную `x` пустой строкой.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * @param {string} doc
 *
 * @returns {string}
 */


function removeVowels(doc) {
  // write code here
    let al = [ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y',
               'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y' ];
    let result = "";
     
    for(let i = 0; i < doc.length; i++)
    {
         
        if (!al.includes(doc[i]))
        {
            result += doc[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]